# SSJS Automation Studio - Read imported CSV file

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, csv

I'm new to SSJS and Automation Studio. What I'm trying to achieve is a simple automation based on the CSV File Drop -

```
File Drop -> Script
```

After a CSV file was dropped into a specified location, then we execute SSJS script that needs to read the CSV file content create a JSON object out of it and send JSON object to API server.

So my question would be - **is there any documentation on how to read a CSV file that was dropped via File Drop step in Automation Studio?** I cannot find anything helpful except folder functions - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_folderRetrieve.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to import that file into a Data Extension first. None of Marketing Cloud's scripting languages (SSJS, AMPscript, SQL, or GTL) can touch the SFTP or anything on it. You will need to use the Import activity to move this into a Data Extension, which is then something that can be access via SSJS, etc.

So automation would need to be: `File Drop > Import > Script`